# Double quotes in bytes object vs double qoutes in flask response data

Tags: python, escaping, html-escape-characters

I'm writing some assertions for a flask application. I've successfully tested for Umlauts in the response like so:

`assert 'Wählen Sie ...'.encode('utf-8') in rv.data`

The Umlaut "ä" has the same represenation (`\xc3\xa4`) in both the encoded data and the response from the web application.

But now, I'm trying to do the same with double quotes:

`assert 'Der gewünschte Monat ... z.B. "2019-5".'.encode('utf-8') in rv.data`

which fails, because `"` is still `"` when it is encoded, but the web application responds with `&#34;` instead.

What should I do with the string I am testing for in order to achieve compatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web application is using html entity codes to encode the double quotes before encoding to utf-8.  You *could* use the [html.escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape) function to simulate this, but unfortunately it replaces '"' with `&quot;` rather than `&#34;`.

The [xml.sax.saxutils.escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.utils.html#xml.sax.saxutils.escape) function does not automatically escape double quotes, but it does accept a dictionary of characters to escape and the escaped values, so you can use this to generate the text:

```
>>> from xml.sax import saxutils
>>> escaped = saxutils.escape('Der gewünschte Monat ... z.B. "2019-5".', {'"': '&#34;'})
>>> escaped
'Der gewünschte Monat ... z.B. &#34;2019-5&#34;.'
```

The reverse approach would be to decode and unescape the server response and compare it with the original string.  You can use the [html.unescape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) function for this, as it will unescape the numeric escape:

```
>>> import html
>>> response = html.unescape(rv.data.decode('utf-8'))
>>> assert 'Der gewünschte Monat ... z.B. "2019-5".'.encode('utf-8') in response
```